# Retrieve random record from database each time i need it or get all records when app starts, put them into list and pick random record from this list?

Tags: android, database

I need to get random records from a database in my Android app pretty often. 
Is it better to retrieve all records from database into a list(when app launches) and then randomly pick record form the list? Or do a query to database every time i need to pull random record?

Comment: do a query to database every time is better one

Comment: You could just try both and measure the time